# can someone explain how to interpret this logcat?

Tags: android, logcat

```
02:41:30.402 Error AndroidRuntime 256  *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
02:41:30.403 Error AndroidRuntime 256  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard$State.ICC_FAIL
02:41:30.403 Error AndroidRuntime 256   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.KeyguardViewMediator.doKeyguard(KeyguardViewMediator.java:637)
02:41:30.403 Error AndroidRuntime 256   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.KeyguardViewMediator.onSystemReady(KeyguardViewMediator.java:348)
02:41:30.403 Error AndroidRuntime 256   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.systemReady(PhoneWindowManager.java:3520)
02:41:30.403 Error AndroidRuntime 256   at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.systemReady(WindowManagerService.java:5934)
02:41:30.403 Error AndroidRuntime 256   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:656)
```

Comment: Are you sure State.ICC_FAIL is not internal variable which shouldn't be used by developers or maybe it's not available in your android version? Looks like this is the problem (NoSuchFieldError).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running a custom ROM or built your own ROM and something is wrong with the build.